# How would I be able to have certain lines of code be executed randomly?

Tags: python, math, random, statistics

I feel this should be an obvious answer, however, I am having issues coding a personal project of mine. How would I be able to have certain lines of code be executed randomly?

Not from the project itself but the principles are still, say for example ***I would want the following code to be executed every 1/1000 times or so.***

```
print("Lucky!")
```

How would I exactly be able to do that?

Comment: Do you want to load the code snippets dynamically or are they hardcoded?

Answer (score 0):

Set a [trace function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) that will have a 1/1000 chance to print:

```
import random, sys
def trace(frame, event, arg):
  if random.random() < 1/1000:
    print("Lucky!")
  return trace

sys.settrace(trace)
```

You're welcome to test it with a 1/2 chance.

Comment: Thank you! Now, How would I be able to make something 5/100 chance then?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a random integer in the range [0,1000). Pick any single value in the range, and check for equality to see if you should print.

```python
import random

def lucky():
    if random.randrange(1000) == 42:
        print("Lucky!")
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, How would I be able to make something 5/100 chance then?

Comment: 5/100 == 1/20, so change the argument to `randrange()` accordingly. Alternatively, check for a range of outcomes: `randrange(100) < 5`. (Recall that `randrange()` results include 0.)

Comment: This approach works well with rational probabilities but if you're dealing with irrationals like 1/Pi or 1/e, you should use `random.random()` to get random floats in the range (0,1).